Compiling kernel modules for a Terramaster NAS
I'm having a bit of trouble with compiling the Coral AI PCIe drivers for my Terramaster NAS. Terramaster support has been no use at all. However, one other user has managed to compile some modules to support certain USB devices, so I'm trying to muddle through and figure out how they did it.
The NAS operating system has no package manager, so figuring out dependencies for compiling is tricky. It's running a Linux 5.15.59 kernel on an x86_64 Intel CPU. Instead, I've tried compiling on my Windows laptop running WSL Ubuntu 22.04 (Linux 5.15.146).
Here's the steps I've taken:

Downloaded the GPL source code from the Terramaster site:
wget https://download2.terra-master.com/TerraMaster_X86_GPL_Source_Code.tar


Extracted the linux-5.15.59 source from the tarball

Ran make defconfig and make prepare inside the linux source folder

Cloned the official repo for the source code

Edited the Makefile to point to the linux source code from step 2

Run make


At this point, I got 2 .ko files, apex.ko and gasket.ko. However, I did get some warnings and I'm not sure if these may be related to the final error:
$ make
make -C ~/TerraMasterSourceCode/linux-5.15.59 M=/home/andy/gasket-driver/src modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/andy/TerraMasterSourceCode/linux-5.15.59'
  CC [M]  /home/andy/gasket-driver/src/gasket_core.o
  CC [M]  /home/andy/gasket-driver/src/gasket_ioctl.o
  CC [M]  /home/andy/gasket-driver/src/gasket_interrupt.o
  CC [M]  /home/andy/gasket-driver/src/gasket_page_table.o
  CC [M]  /home/andy/gasket-driver/src/gasket_sysfs.o
  LD [M]  /home/andy/gasket-driver/src/gasket.o
  CC [M]  /home/andy/gasket-driver/src/apex_driver.o
  LD [M]  /home/andy/gasket-driver/src/apex.o
WARNING: Symbol version dump "Module.symvers" is missing.
         Modules may not have dependencies or modversions.
         You may get many unresolved symbol warnings.
  MODPOST /home/andy/gasket-driver/src/Module.symvers
WARNING: modpost: "system_wq" [/home/andy/gasket-driver/src/apex.ko] undefined!
WARNING: modpost: "kmalloc_caches" [/home/andy/gasket-driver/src/apex.ko] undefined!
WARNING: modpost: "param_ops_int" [/home/andy/gasket-driver/src/apex.ko] undefined!
WARNING: modpost: "pci_disable_device" [/home/andy/gasket-driver/src/apex.ko] undefined!
WARNING: modpost: "delayed_work_timer_fn" [/home/andy/gasket-driver/src/apex.ko] undefined!
WARNING: modpost: "param_ops_bool" [/home/andy/gasket-driver/src/apex.ko] undefined!
WARNING: modpost: "init_timer_key" [/home/andy/gasket-driver/src/apex.ko] undefined!
WARNING: modpost: "cancel_delayed_work_sync" [/home/andy/gasket-driver/src/apex.ko] undefined!
WARNING: modpost: "mutex_unlock" [/home/andy/gasket-driver/src/apex.ko] undefined!
WARNING: modpost: "pci_bus_assign_resources" [/home/andy/gasket-driver/src/apex.ko] undefined!
WARNING: modpost: suppressed 113 unresolved symbol warnings because there were too many)
  CC [M]  /home/andy/gasket-driver/src/apex.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/andy/gasket-driver/src/apex.ko
  CC [M]  /home/andy/gasket-driver/src/gasket.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/andy/gasket-driver/src/gasket.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/andy/TerraMasterSourceCode/linux-5.15.59'

I have a feeling those warnings are related to the issue at hand. There is a Module.symvers file in the driver source directory. There's also a modules-only.symvers file inside the linux source directory. I'm not sure if I need to do something with those files. In any case, I thought I'd try installing the modules anyway with insmod. I transferred them to my NAS and ran the command, resulting in:
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module gasket.ko: Unknown symbol in module
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module apex.ko: Unknown symbol in module

I checked the dmesg output and it looks like some dependency issues:
[509064.343783] gasket: Unknown symbol __x86_indirect_thunk_rax (err -2)
[509064.343811] gasket: Unknown symbol __x86_indirect_thunk_r13 (err -2)
[509064.343821] gasket: Unknown symbol __x86_return_thunk (err -2)
[595300.167534] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_wait_with_reschedule (err -2)
[595300.167547] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_disable_device (err -2)
[595300.167552] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_sysfs_put_attr (err -2)
[595300.167559] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_page_table_num_active_pages (err -2)
[595300.167563] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_unregister_device (err -2)
[595300.167566] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_sysfs_create_entries (err -2)
[595300.167570] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_interrupt_msix_cleanup (err -2)
[595300.167572] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_pci_add_device (err -2)
[595300.167575] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_reset_nolock (err -2)
[595300.167580] apex: Unknown symbol __x86_return_thunk (err -2)
[595300.167583] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_enable_device (err -2)
[595300.167590] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_sysfs_get_attr (err -2)
[595300.167592] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_sysfs_put_device_data (err -2)
[595300.167596] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_pci_remove_device (err -2)
[595300.167599] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_page_table_num_entries (err -2)
[595300.167601] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_interrupt_reinit (err -2)
[595300.167604] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_register_device (err -2)
[595300.167606] apex: Unknown symbol gasket_sysfs_get_device_data (err -2)

I'm a bit stuck here. I tried searching for the unknown symbols but couldn't turn anything up. Am I missing a dependency, have I missed a step somewhere?

[509064.343783] gasket: Unknown symbol __x86_indirect_thunk_rax (err -2)
[...]
[595300.167580] apex: Unknown symbol __x86_return_thunk (err -2)

If you're using Terramaster provided source, then defconfig is likely different from the kernel config used by Terramaster NAS.
Note that unless you can find a driver version compatible with Terramaster's kernel (or a newer kernel release), it may require some driver patching to make them compatible.
What's the reason for using their kernel in the first place? Do they distribute some code that's not been upstreamed? It might be easier to ditch Terramaster's kernel if it's not just a config issue.

Terramaster provide only the GPL source files, not the config or anything else to support compiling. The config is also not on the filesystem as far as I can tell. I reached out to their support to ask if they could supply the config and they told me they couldn't help me.
I hoped the default config would work, but I guess not.

No sense letting the bounty go to waste!
